# Question about bug in ksh

Tags: ksh

I've found following function in our old scripts:

```
f() {    # < files list
   typeset file
   cat - > $TMPFILE   # Bug in KSH
   while read -r file
   do
      process $file
   done < $TMPFILE
}
```

Does anyone know this bug in KSH?

Comment: You might do better on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently f() is a *filter function*, i.e. you are supposed to use it in a pipe like so

```
./generate_filelist.sh | f
```

Where you'd expect `read -r` to read stdin just fine, e.g. when doing

```
./generate_filelist.sh | while read -r file; do echo $file; done
```

apparently, there is (was?) a bug in (certain) ksh (version(s)) that prevented the same to work from a function:

```
f() {
   typeset file
   while read -r file # whoops not reading from stdin as it should?
   do
      process $file
   done
}
```

I foun two bugs that could be it, depending mostly on your platform:

- [flawed stream input optimization on MacOS](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/ast-users/2005q4/000730.html)
- alleged [signal suppression in IllumOS](https://www.illumos.org/issues/745) (Open Solaris derivative)

There are possibly (many) more historical bugs that could apply, and I stopped searching because I don't know anything about your platform, or indeed the platform the script was designed for.

So instead there has been a workaround involving writing the stdin to a temporary file, and reading from that. Note that

- this changes semantics (reading starts after full file received only)
- there seems to be a typo (`$$TMPFILE`, probably instead of `$TMPFILE`?) in your sample (unless there is one more feature of KSH I wasn't aware of, `$$` expands to the current process Id))

.

```
f() {
   typeset file
   cat - > $TMPFILE
   while read -r file
   do
      process $file
   done < $TMPFILE
}
```